# Flex Event Listener Callback Not Firing

Tags: apache-flex, events, flex4, callback

Maybe you can help point me in the right direction on this.  In our app, I am periodically noticing that a particular event handler is not firing.  99% of the time, it works fine, but, every so often, it just dies.   How can I find out whats happening?  Is the DispatchEvent() not happening/working somehow?  Is my listener still listening?  Did something else catch the event, and not pass it along so that the 'right' listener can get to it ?

Here's a little bit of the code...
[image: code]

Thats a somewhat pruned down version of what the real code is, but I don't think I trimmed out anything important.  The key, as I see it is that we fire up the params dialog, then start to listen for the closed event.  Then, we show the param dialogs close function.  What happens when it fails is that the trace message "caught close event.." is never generated, and, consequently, the closeHandler is not getting called at all.

I don't see anything out of place there, do you?

So, what tools are at my disposal to track this little bugger down?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're handling the removal of your component from the displaylist from inside the component. You dispatch the CLOSE event before you actually remove it, but it may very well arrive when the object is already removed. That's due to the asynchronous nature of events. This means that every once in a while the function that handles the event, simply doesn't exist anymore when the event arrives. Certainly if you use a weak reference.

**solution**

Now to solve the issue:

- you could handle the close event outside of your component
- if you want to keep the handler inside the component, you could remove the component in the eventhandler. Keep in mind that inside that closure you can not use `PopUpManager.removePopUp(this)`, since 'this' doesn't refer to the component, but to the closure itself.
- you could *not* use a weak reference, but that's not a very good idea, since your component won't be garbagecollected because of that. That is unless you remove the event listener manually from within the closure,

like this:

```
var closeHandler:function = function(e:CloseEvent):void {
    trace("...");
    var p:Params = e.currentTarget as Params;
    p.removeEventListener(CloseEvent.CLOSE, closeHandler);

    /* other code that you want to execute in the closure */
}

var p:Params = PopUpManager.createPopUp(myApp, Params, true) as Params);
p.addEventListener(CloseEvent.CLOSE, closeHandler);
PopUpManager.centerPopUp(p);
```

Comment: Thats a recent change, as an attempt to fix the bug.  In the code I trimmed out, the original removal was happening inside the sometimes-not-firing-closeHandler, which was actually worse behavior, because it would leave a modal dialog over the app, with no hope of getting around it, forcing the user to have to restart.  At least this way, it just fails silently, confusing them, but allowing them to continue from just before they lost control.

Comment: If you used `PopUpManager.removePopUp(this)` inside the closure, I can imagine it fails. 'this' would then reference the closure and not the component that you want to remove.

Comment: I used ... PopUpManager.removePopUp(p); ... in the closure, where p is the dialog.   At the same time, other things that are supposed to happen in the closure also are not happening.  The trace message, the advancing of the token.step, and the call to reportShowMCP(token);

Comment: OK. I kind of misinterpreted your pruned code. Didn't realize the second function was on a different class. In that case just don't use the weak reference and remove the eventlistener in the closure. The weak reference is the reason the closure doesn't get called because the dispatcher may already be garbagecollected.

Comment: hmm...thats a possibility...I'll give it a try, and see if I can break it.  Unfortunately, I can never get it to break when I want it to, it only happens when I need it to work!  However, I don't know if I know what you mean after all.  I don't have an event listener in the closure.  Do you mean to put the remove pop up back into the closure ?

Comment: Well, I've written and AHK script to test this 500 times, and so far, it worked every time...I'm going to mark this as resolved.  THanks!

Comment: "you could not use a weak reference, but that's not a very good idea" - Actually, using weak references is bad form because it might GC before it runs *and* it means that the GC needs to run for longer when trying to see if it should garbage collect or not.  Always use strong references when possible and clean them up manually.

Comment: @J_A_X I do. IMO weak references cause unpredictable, hard to test/debug behaviour (as @reidLinden has just proven ;) ). It's just that even the Adobe big shots recommend it. I didn't know it kept the GC run for longer though. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I can't say I've *ever* heard someone from Adobe recommend it.  Maybe for a small app where the developers don't know any better, but still.  And yeah, the GC has 2 ways to garbage collect, one is reference counting and the other is flagging.  Reference counting is cheaper (if references == 0, GC) while flagging needs to check all other references, and references to that, etc until it finds that it's not needed anymore, then GC.

Comment: Grant Skinner for one: http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2006/07/as3_weakly_refe.html . He does point out though that the one case where it might be an issue is with anonymous functions...